# Why are Meteor's Match patterns capitalized?

Tags: meteor, naming-conventions, eslint

Meteor's [`Match`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/check.html#matchpatterns) patterns are capitalized, eg. `Match.Any`, `Match.Optional`.

This goes against the convention that all uppercase-started functions be called with `new` operators, eg. as embodied in eslint's [`new-cap`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/new-cap) rule with `capIsNew` true (the default setting).

What convention is Match following here?

Comment: Btw, I realize you can make exceptions with eslint for each Match pattern by using eg. /* eslint new-cap: ["error", { "capIsNewExceptions": ["Match.Optional", "Match.Any"] }] */)

Comment: Internally those are actually classes: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/check/match.js

Comment: @Jankapunkt Even though the source code shows classes indeed, the accessible properties `Match.Optional` etc. look rather like _factories_ (i.e. functions that return an _instance_ of the corresponding class).